# Invalid syntax for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery, syntax-error

I'm trying to execute the following query in SQL Server, but it's throwing an error. How can I fix it?

```
select 
    T.T_Email
from 
    Stu_Question S, Tutor_Answer T
where 
    S.S_Quest_Id = '4f7a1518-a765-40c0-ae53-3ee61eef6673' 
    and S.S_Quest_Id = T.S_Quest_Id 
    and (T_Email,T_Answer_Update_Status) 
        IN (T_Email, Select MAX(T_Answer_Update_Status) 
                     from Tutor_Answer 
                     where S_Quest_Id='4f7a1518-a765-40c0-ae53-3ee61eef6673' 
                     group by T_Email)
    and S.S_Quest_Update_Status = (Select MAX(S_Quest_Update_Status) 
                                   from Stu_Question 
                                   where S_Quest_Id='4f7a1518-a765-40c0-ae53-3ee61eef6673')
```

Comment: And what is your error?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`marc_s` correctly pointed out the offending part of your query.

You'll have to try to convert that to a join instead. Here is how I would do it:

```
select T.T_Email
  from Stu_Question S
  join (select T_Email, 
               row_number() over (partition by S_Quest_Id order by S_Quest_Update_Status desc) as rn
          from Tutor_Answer) T
    on T.S_Quest_Id=S.S_Quest_Id 
   and T.rn = 1
 where S.S_Quest_Id='4f7a1518-a765-40c0-ae53-3ee61eef6673'
   AND S.S_Quest_Update_Status=(Select MAX(S_Quest_Update_Status)
                                 from Stu_Question 
                                where S_Quest_Id='4f7a1518-a765-40c0-ae53-3ee61eef6673')
```

Notice that you can definitely improve this further.  But it should get you going.

Comment: Bro there is no in problem boss i want to change it in according to sql server pairwise query it's written in oracle it's runiing corectly if i remove from subquery T_Email column from select statement it's running correctly but i want to return both column bosss from subquery......

Comment: Boss i want to get multiple column from subquery but idon't know how to done it....... & i use in because it's returning multiple rowssss because of Group By clause i also need use of it

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support multiple column `in` clauses like Oracle does.  The alternative is converting to a join like I did.  Have you even tried the query I posted?  It should do the same thing your query intended to do.

Comment: Yep I tried your query there is an error inthis statement  T.S_Quest_Id=S.S_Quest_Id

Comment: I done it correctly by myself thank you for your help guyss thanks aloot

Answer (score 4):

This is the offending part of your statement:

```
and (T_Email,T_Answer_Update_Status) 
    IN (T_Email, Select MAX(T_Answer_Update_Status) 
                 from Tutor_Answer 
                 where S_Quest_Id='4f7a1518-a765-40c0-ae53-3ee61eef6673' 
                 group by T_Email)
```

What on earth are you trying to do here???

T-SQL's `IN` operator works on **one** column at a time - like this:

```
WHERE T_EMail IN (SELECT EMail FROM .....)
```

Comment: Bro there is no in problem boss i want to change it in according to sql server pairwise query it's written in oracle it's runiing corectly if i remove from subquery T_Email from select statement it's running correctly but i want both column bosss